# Why do I have a strange kink at the edges of the tiles?

Tags: tilesize

I'm using Blender Render, a 90° FOV Camera. My Tiles are 512x512.

But when rendering, there is something strange happening at the edges of the tiles. Does anybody know something about it?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ah, i found the problem myself!

I set the camera to **Panoramic** instead of **Perspective**

Now I changed it to Perspektive and the edges are gone.